# Swift Code optimization for finding nearest target cgfloat from an array

Tags: swift, compiler-errors

I would like to develop a method which search the nearest cgfloat from an array to target value.

When it comes to the implantation, it takes 1s to compile. Would anybody please tell us the better way which can also minis the compilation time of the following code block?

Warning:

```
Instance method 'nearest(to:)' took 1016ms to type-check (limit: 300ms)
```

My work :

```
extension Array where Element == CGFloat {
    func nearest(to x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        let result = self.min(by: {abs($0 - x) < abs($1 - x)})
        return  result ?? .zero 
        //return self.reduce(self.first!) { abs($1 - x) < abs($0 - x) ? $1 : $0 }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add in explicit type information:

```
func nearest(to x:  CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
    let f: (CGFloat, CGFloat) -> Bool = { (lhs: CGFloat, rhs: CGFloat) in
        abs(lhs - x) < abs(rhs - x)
    }
    
    let result: CGFloat? = self.min(by: f)
    return result ?? CGFloat.zero
}
```